# multi-dimensional associative array with unknown error in php5.4

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to output all the data in my multidimensional array, but I keep getting an unknown error when I run it in the browser.  As far as I can tell I've done everything correct.  I've played around with single and double quotes as well, still no luck.  Hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can make something out.

```
$goods = array( 
    'foods'  => array(
            "desert"    => "chocolate cake",
            "fruit"     => "fuji apples",
            "veggies"   => "baby carrots",
            "poultry"   => "grilled chicken"),
    'drinks' => array(
            "soda"      => "coca cola",
            "juice"     => "florida orange",
            "coffee"    => "black",
            "beer"      => "heineken"););

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($goods as $section => $items)
    foreach ($items as $key => $description)
        echo "$section:\t$key\t($description)<br>";
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: there is a semicolon after heineken that shouldn't be there ....

Comment: try IDE with syntax errors highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$goods = array( 
    'foods'  => array(
            "desert"    => "chocolate cake",
            "fruit"     => "fuji apples",
            "veggies"   => "baby carrots",
            "poultry"   => "grilled chicken"),
    'drinks' => array(
            "soda"      => "coca cola",
            "juice"     => "florida orange",
            "coffee"    => "black",
            "beer"      => "heineken"););
//REMOVE THAT SEMICOLON -->           ^
```

And it will work...

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew a fresh pair of eyes would help!

Comment: You are welcom but as they suggested in the comments of your question: Use an IDE, it normally can track those kind of mistakes instantly so you can focus on the really hard tasks. If you are on windows try visual studio or phpdeveloper or similar. On OSX I like a lot panic coda, or netbeans or whatever...